# Why would I put e.preventDefault() at the beginning of my async function?

Tags: reactjs, forms, async-await, event-handling

I'm still developing my understanding of async functions and ReactJS, but in the context of a form submission, why might I start my async function with `e.preventDefault()?`

I saw this code as an example of how to post form data in React (see article [link](https://www.techomoro.com/submit-a-form-data-to-rest-api-in-a-react-app/)), but they didn't explain why their code begins with `e.preventDefault()`. I'm not sure if this has to do with the async feature, how React renders things, or any other concept I'm not grasping.

I thought `e.preventDefault()` would prevent the form from submitting, so I'm reading this code (which is tied to the "onSubmit" attribute of a form element), as "anytime I submit a form, the submission will be automatically cancelled".

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

```
let handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      let res = await fetch("https://httpbin.org/post", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          name: name,
          email: email,
          mobileNumber: mobileNumber,
        }),
      });
      let resJson = await res.json();
      if (res.status === 200) {
        setName("");
        setEmail("");
        setMessage("User created successfully");
      } else {
        setMessage("Some error occured");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

Comment: `I thought e.preventDefault() would prevent the form from submitting, so I'm reading this code (which is tied to the "onSubmit" attribute of a form element), as "anytime I submit a form, the submission will be automatically cancelled".` Thats exactly what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`event.preventDefault()` stops the default behavior of an action. Often times we call this in a vanilla HTML form "Submit" operation.

If you're curious, the default behavior of a submit on a form can be read about here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#method

To answer your question, this is stopping all of the default behavior that would normally occur when submitting a form. The code following is what you actually want to happen when submitting.